# Prevent Cracking Singleton using reflection

Tags: java, design-patterns

I came across the below example where a singleton class can be instantiated using reflections. The code is like below

```
public class SingletonExploitationExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        MySingleTon.getInstance();
        Constructor<MySingleTon> constructor = MySingleTon.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        MySingleTon obj1 = constructor.newInstance();
        MySingleTon obj2 = constructor.newInstance();
        MySingleTon obj3 = constructor.newInstance();
        obj1.printN();
    }
}

final class MySingleTon {
    private static MySingleTon instance = null;

    private static int count = 0;
    private MySingleTon(){
        count++;
    }

    public void printN(){
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    public static MySingleTon getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            synchronized (MySingleTon.class){
                if(instance == null){
                    instance = new MySingleTon();
                }

            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Is there any way this can be avoided or a singleton be made to have only one instance(with reflection also user should not be able to instantiate a new object) ?

Comment: Well, the general answer will lean towards a *no*. But can you please add as to why you need such capability? What is your use-case? Just curious.

Comment: @inquisitive just curios to know whether there is a way? :)

Comment: Just don't use singletons.

Comment: @LewBloch why ?

Comment: Because they are rarely necessary. OK, I generalized​, but nearly no one uses singleton correctly in my experience, and nearly always when it isn't necessary. For most use cases we don't need to enforce the singleton property in code. When we do need to, and it does happen sometimes, then the `enum` is almost certainly the correct implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with `enum`s!

Enums make powerful thread-safe, "classloader-safe" singletons, and cannot be initialized through reflection!

Here's an example.

```
enum Foo {
    INSTANCE;
}

Class<?> fooClass = Foo.class;
Constructor<?> c = fooClass.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
c.setAccessible(true);
Foo f = (Foo)c.newInstance();
```

**Output**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot reflectively create enum objects
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at ...
```

Comment: Hey, that's pretty nifty. How about with `Unsafe`?

Comment: @Mena Can you please show a complete example using my code above?

Comment: And let's not forget deserialization as an attack vector. Enums are safe against that too.

Comment: @robin well, I'm using the relevant part of your code above, i.e. getting a declared constructor, setting it accessible and attempting to get an instance of the class. The rest of your code is about the singleton itself, hence not relevant with enums, right?

Comment: @Mena you mean your code is only about avoiding access using reflection and I cannot use it to create singleton ?

Comment: Well, reflection is sort of like the parlor trick. You can do lots of things with it already. But if you break out the heavy guns with `sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance(Foo.class);` that probably works just fine. Therefore it's not a good idea to assume that you can keep actually sensitive information secret within Java.

Comment: @robin read my answer. An enum when used as above **is** a singleton. You can add a convenience method `getInstance` to return the only instance (`INSTANCE`) if you wish to maintain the same syntax, etc. but essentially you only need to refactor `MySingleton` into an `enum`.

Comment: @Kayaman aah the dreaded `sun.misc.Unsafe`. I haven't tried that but I suspect you're right...

Comment: @Mena Thank you very much, I understood your answer and i was able to do the same with ENUM, and yes you are correct I can access enum with the sun.misc.Unsafe

Comment: @robin you're welcome! Thank Kayaman for the sun.misc.Unsafe exploit

Comment: @Mena, "The rest of your code is about the singleton itself, hence not relevant with enums, right?" Wrong. Enums are the standard and best way to implement the singleton antipattern.

Comment: @Lewbloch that's semantics. And enums may not be the recommended solution for platforms with a limited memory.

Comment: Sorry, "semantics" is supposed to be some kind of argument against anything? "Semantics" means "meaning", and is at the heart of correct programming. You had better attend to semantics, and attend well! This doesn't apply to you, of course, but mostly when people say "that's semantics" it means they don't understand the issue or the answer. And enums don't incur as much memory overhead as other singleton implementations​. So enums remain the optimal implementation of the singleton​ antipattern in nearly all use cases.

Comment: @LewBloch Semantics also implies the study of idiomatic expressions, most of which, albeit "incorrect", evolve to form part of the language (i.e. from "parole" to "langue", quoting old Saussure). So to clarify: "that's semantics" means, in this instance, that when you imply that my rhetorical question "The rest of your code is about the singleton itself, hence not relevant with enums, right?" is an actual question aimed at inferring whether the rest of OP's code is relevant to enums, is, uh, "semantics", or rather, your own forced interpretation of a significance I was not aiming at conveying.

Comment: @LewBloch as the saying goes, "arguing with a programmer is like wrestling in the mud with a pig, after some time you realize the pig actually enjoys it." :)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to worry about `Unsafe`. You either have control over class loading and security managers, in which case you can "ban" `Unsafe` or you don't, and the attacker can just intercept and modify your byte code during class loading. Secure code in general only makes sense in a context where you control the environment but are forced to run potentially unsafe code in it.